# weird error in hive query:SemanticException Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I want a set of random data from hive, for example row_number between 772001 and 773000.

My sql is as below:

```
select *  from (
        select *, row_number() over (order by `name`) as row_dsa  
               from  `jck_bonc_demo`.`frjc_jbxx`
       )tmp_table where row_dsa between 772001 and 773000
```

and I get the following error:

> [Cloudera][Hardy] (80) Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown in
>   server while executing query. Error message from server: Error while
>   compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Failed to breakup
>   Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend
>   on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies.

What can I do for this error, anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the syntax you want:

```
select * 
from (select *, row_number() over (order by `name`) as row_dsa  
      from  `jck_bonc_demo`.`frjc_jbxx`
     ) x
where row_dsa between 772001 and 773000;
```

You need a subquery to use `row_dsa` in a `where` clause.

Comment: sorry, I miss a '）’ in my question describe, the problem still exists @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

Use `select s.*, ...` (with table alias) if you want to select all from table plus one more calculated column, not `select *`. Also, no need to back-quote non-reserved words:

```
select * 
from (select s.*, row_number() over (order by name) as row_dsa  
      from jck_bonc_demo.frjc_jbxx s
     ) x
where row_dsa between 772001 and 773000;
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a bug in my program,name is not the col of the specified table,the error message is weird. Tanks for your answer @Gordon Linoff @eftjoin